# Can I use the same Unity cache server for multiple projects?

Tags: caching, server, unity-game-engine

I set up a Unity cache server for a small team, can I use this server for other projects?
or should I set a dedicated server for each project?

Regards,

Comment: You mean, other projects with another team? Or other projects with the same team?

Comment: @RicardoReiter : I mean other projects with another team.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended practice is to set up one instance of the Cache Server per project.
You can do so by running multiple servers on multiple machine, or running them on the same machine listening on different port.

This is what has been said by [Stephen Palmer on Unity's blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/20/cache-server-6-0-release-and-retrospective-optimizing-import/#div-comment-371566):

> The safest thing to do is run separate instances per project, using unique port numbers for each.